# How to fix error JSX element type 'X' does not have any construct or call signatures in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I trying to define `icon` as JSX.Element type in a config file but I getting an error with TypeScript when using this config to render in component. How I can fix it?

> JSX element type 'Icon' does not have any construct or call
> signatures.ts(2604) 'Icon' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its type
> 'Element' is not a valid JSX element type.ts(2786)

user-config.ts

```
export interface UserConfig {
    text: string;
    value: string;
    icon?: JSX.Element;
}

export const userConfig: UserConfig[] = [
    {
        text: 'John',
        value: 'john-123',
        icon: UserIcon,
    },
    {
        text: 'Doe',
        value: 'doe-456',
        icon: UserIcon,
    },
];
```

index.tsx

```
    <div>
            {userConfig.map(({ text, value, icon: Icon }, index) => (
                <div key={index} className="flex items-center justify-start flex-col">
                    {Icon && <Icon />}
                    <span data-user={value}>{text}</span>
                </div>
            ))}
      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be just `JSX.Element`. It should be a function that returns a `JSX.Element`:

```
type Props = {
  Icon?: () => JSX.Element
}

const Component: React.FC<Props> = ({ Icon = null }) => {
  return <div>{
    Icon && <Icon /> // no error
  }</div>
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgAUcwBnOAXjgG9y44BJNBAB2AfgBccABQBKDgD44AKQDKADQB0AUQA2SEEmExyAX0pDhLeAGFckYYZiTk6GBoBi1gDxMIrRZxSXAIWHHDCAK46OnAmcuyKPHxEMBFQwnBeACbAAG7ySXwhInAAZKWZgiUA9IrV1eEQcEhQOFC8sV7VOfmmQA)

Comment: Can you explain for me know why it is a function ? because I see it already an SVG element

Comment: JSX.Element is `<div></div`. But you expect a function  that returns a jsx, since you sre calling it. In your current version it is something like this: <<div></div>/>